# "Container clusters" web view doesn't load on Console

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

As the title says. I have uploaded several images and can see them under "Container Registry"

I have created a cluster using "gcloud container clusters create". But I cannot view the "container cluster" page on the Container Engine Console - it just gets stuck with a spinning circle symbol.

Update: after posting a feedback comment, the problem was resolved.

Comment: Have you tried to refresh the page? Did you only create a single cluster or have you created multiple clusters? Can you list your clusters using gcloud (`gcloud container clusters list --project=PROJECT`)?

Comment: @RobertBailey yes, on multiple computers. Yes I can list the clusters via glcoud. Not sure what is going on. What does it usually look like?

Comment: Normally the page loads and shows a list of your clusters. Can you use the report feedback button in the UI or does that not show up either? If not, can you use it on the container registry page and explain your issue so that we can debug further? thanks.

Comment: @RobertBailey this is what I see http://imgur.com/E7UpLKN. Yes I appear to be able to click the "Send Feedback" icon. I will try.

Comment: Thanks. Sending feedback will help the developers debug why your project is experiencing issues.